# How do I check this series' convergence via comparison?

Tags: improper-integrals

Given Integral: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^3+1}$$

I have to test its convergence.

I am having problem in integrating it.
So far, I have reduced it to the partial fraction:

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\int^p_0\frac{dx}{3(x+1)}+\int^p_0\frac{(2-x)\,dx}{3(x^2-x+1)}$$

But How do I proceed after this?

Comment: Well, you might need to split up the region.  For instance, for $x\in [0,1]$ the integrand is $≤ 1$.  Can you handle the region $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: Why do you mention a series in your title ? It is an integral you are working on...

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to use the fact that, in $[1,+\infty)$, $\frac1{x^3+1}<\frac1{x^3}$. Therefore$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac1{x^3+1}\,\mathrm dx<\int_1^{+\infty}\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm dx=\frac12.$$